# Disposing a cloned object also disposes the reference object

Tags: xamarin.ios

```
UIColor foo = (UIColor) bar.Copy();
foo.Dispose();
```

I am observing that the above code causes `bar` to also be disposed. Based on the documentation, `foo` should be a new instance of `bar` and therefore I would expect that `bar` would not be affected by any changes made to `foo`.

Can someone explain why this is happening? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something... If so, is there another way to get a copy of a `UIColor` without having to copy over all of the property values myself?